# Why seemingly equivalent object constructions produce different warnings in C++?

Tags: c++, warnings

I am rather surprised that 3 object constructions, which I considered equivalent, actually produce different compiler warnings or even an error:

```
struct B { int &&a = {}; };

int main()
{
    [[maybe_unused]] auto x = B{}; //ok in clang and gcc
    [[maybe_unused]] B y{}; //clang warning
    [[maybe_unused]] B z; //gcc warning and clang error
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WzfrzWWbe

GCC warning about `z`:

```
warning: a temporary bound to 'B::a' only persists until the constructor exits [-Wextra]
```

Clang warning about `y`:

```
warning: sorry, lifetime extension of temporary created by aggregate initialization using default member initializer is not supported; lifetime of temporary will end at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling]
```

Clang error about `z`:

```
 error: reference member 'a' binds to a temporary object whose lifetime would be shorter than the lifetime of the constructed object
```

Could you please explain what is the difference between these 3 construction methods?

Comment: Please remember to make questions *self-contained*. If you ask about compiler messages, then please include them copy-pasted as text inside the question itself.

Comment: Clang is returning an error and not a warning for z: "error: reference member 'a' binds to a temporary object whose lifetime would be shorter than the lifetime of the constructed object
struct B"

Comment: The example can be simplified removing the struct A and using int instead, same pattern of warnings. Also, this [[maybe_unused]] B b = B{}; produce no warnings as [[maybe_unused]] auto x = B{};

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi, thanks, I updated the question based on your findings